# upgrade an old iMac

Tags: macos

I have an old iMac 24 2.8 of 2008. Is it a good idea to upgrade to Yosemite?
Now it has Mac OS 10.9.5. It has 1TB hard drive, 4GB Ram. 
Will the upgrade make it go slower? Is it safer to keep the old opeating system?

Answer (score 2):

Everyone gets a different experience, so apart from Googling what other iMac 2,8 users experienced, the best course of action is to see for yourself. Take a Time Machine backup of your computer, get Yosemite, and see how it goes. If anything goes wrong, you can always wipe your hard drive and restore it from the Mavericks backup. (Just remember to find another way to back up important files that you've modified post-upgrade, such as emailing them to yourself or putting them on a flash drive.)

Answer (score 2):

No do not do it. Wait for the next update. You will have at least blurry text in everywhere. Period.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Yosemite with good results on a 2.66 GHz Early 2008 20" iMac (8,1). I have experienced the blurry text issue; selecting "Reduce Transparency" in the Accessibility prefpane solved that problem, and frankly gives a more Mac-like experience overall in my opinion.